# javascript replace() Method for NOWRAP, and Script

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a problem , this is fixed code that I can't change manually.
The question is if it possible with JavaScript replace the actual text inside code??

```
  <td nowrap="nowrap">Код безопасности<span class="myWinError">*</span>:</td>

    <div class="myBtnCont x-unselectable" unselectable="on" id="subbutmyAdvF3" onclick="document.getElementById('submmyAdvF3').click();"><a href="javascript://" onclick="return false;">Отправить</a></div>
```

Any Ideas???

This is the actual pop up box where this elements are

```
<div id="_uwndWnd1" class="xw-plain x-unselectable xw-resize xw-active" unselectable="on" style="position: absolute; width: 400px; z-index: 2; left: 0px; overflow: visible;"><div class="xw-disabled" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 30010; width: 400px; height: 168px; display: none;" unselectable="on"></div><div class="xw-tl" unselectable="on"><div class="xw-tr" unselectable="on"><div class="xw-tc" unselectable="on"><div class="xw-sps" unselectable="on"></div><div class="xw-hdr xw-draggable" unselectable="on"><div class="xt xt-close xt-close2" unselectable="on"></div><div class="xt xt-maxi" unselectable="on" style="display: none;"></div><div class="xt xt-rest" unselectable="on" style="display: none;"></div><div class="xt xt-mini" unselectable="on" style="display: none;"></div><span class="xw-hdr-text" unselectable="on" title="">Užsakyti kuponas</span></div></div></div></div><div class="xw-ml" unselectable="on"><div class="xw-mr" unselectable="on"><div class="xw-mc" unselectable="on"><div class="xw-body" unselectable="on"><div style="overflow: hidden; height: 127px;" unselectable="on"><div class="myWinCont" style="display: none; overflow: hidden;" align="left" unselectable="on"><div align="left" unselectable="on"><div class="myWinLoad" unselectable="on"></div></div></div><div class="myWinCont" style="overflow: auto; width: 378px; display: block; height: 100%;" align="left" unselectable="on">
<form id="myAdvF3" onsubmit="sendAdvice834();return false;">
<table border="0" width="98%" cellspacing="1">

<tbody><tr><td nowrap="nowrap" width="30%">Jūsų e-mail <span class="myWinError">*</span>:</td><td><input maxlength="50" size="30" style="width:100%;" id="adv3f2" name="emailt"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>

<tr><td nowrap="nowrap">Код безопасности <span class="myWinError">*</span>:</td><td><input type="text" name="code" id="adv3code" size="5" maxlength="5" style="font-size:18px !important;padding:6px !important;width:70px !important;"><input type="hidden" name="seckey" value="3788857711912799178"> <img alt="" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;cursor:pointer;" id="adv3secuImg" align="absmiddle" title="Обновить код безопасности" onclick="this.src='http://groziokuponai.ucoz.com/secure/?k=3788857711912799178;s=index;tm='+Math.random();" src="http://groziokuponai.ucoz.com/secure/?k=3788857711912799178;s=index;tm=1371152102"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>
<tr><td id="msgAdv38" align="right"></td><td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" onmousedown="this.className='downBtn'" onmouseover="this.className='overBtn'" onmouseout="this.className='outBtn'">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="myBtnLeft"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://s26.ucoz.net/img/1px.gif"></td>
<td class="myBtnCenter"><div class="myBtnCont x-unselectable" unselectable="on" id="subbutmyAdvF3" onclick="document.getElementById('submmyAdvF3').click();"><a href="javascript://" onclick="return false;">Отправить</a></div></td>
<td class="myBtnRight"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://s26.ucoz.net/img/1px.gif"></td>
<td style="visibility:hidden;"><input type="image" src="http://s26.ucoz.net/img/ma/1px.gif" style="width:1px;" onclick="if($('#subbutmyAdvF3').hasClass('myBtnDis')){return false;}$('#subbutmyAdvF3').addClass('myBtnDis');" name="submmyAdvF3" id="submmyAdvF3"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
    </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="32"><input type="hidden" name="t" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="page" value="http://groziokuponai.ucoz.com/news/pedikiura/2013-05-31-12">
</form>
</div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="xw-bl" unselectable="on"><div class="xw-br" unselectable="on"><div class="xw-bc" unselectable="on"></div></div></div><div class="xw-blank" style="display:none" unselectable="on"></div></div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? Replace existing HTML and its attributes? If so - replace what with what?

Comment: I have already explain the ACTUAL TEXT I just show full piece of code, BUT need to replace this "Код безопасности" and this "Отправить".

Comment: Can you post a bit more of HTML code above and below shown lines? IT should be possible to replace text, but you need a more definitive way to locating elements in question

Comment: Have edited post, have a look

Answer (score 0):

Judging by given markup, following JS code should make the replacement:

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("myWinError")[1].parentNode.innerHTML = 'Кот Шредингера <span class="myWinError">*</span>';
    document.getElementsByClassName("myBtnCont")[0].firstChild.innerHTML = 'Заправить';
</script>
```

Comment: How did you plan to run the JavaScript commands when you have them? Do you have your own page that opens this popup?

Comment: I have template, but I don't have access, to this part of the code and I have to use some how the java script at the top of the page or something like this to change the text.

Comment: I just copy this code using chrome F12, I don't have any access to him(

Comment: This is like the box which pop up.

Comment: So you mean just running the code in browser address bar where you ordinary type the URL? But you can just as well edit the value directly in Chrome F12

Comment: I'm using UCOZ if you know what it is. I can log in into system and create pages and so on but some features I can't edit, and how I find out the only way is use the JavaScript like replace() somehow. I mean I have access to css to html documents and so on... so on... so on BUT pop up box which I mention before I but to MY html like  ADV_2 and It automatically display button.

Comment: Ok, so there's a page that you can edit (CSS, HTML, JavaScript), but this popup you cannot, correct? If so, how does the page *you can edit* is connected to the popup - is there a button that you click on your page to make popup appear? is it inserted into your own page via some kind of code?

Comment: first part yep correct, and for button I just put code to my HTML like ADV_2 and that's it. It will display as button, How I know  basically  is I put ADV_2 it automatically replace with the code when I want open the page. I think the code it on the main server or something like this. So the only way is Overwrite the code with JavaScript some how, and this is basically my question, how to do it)

Comment: If you put in your HTML something like [ADV_2] and it's automatically converted into the HTML that you've shown, then simple inserting the script from my answer below that [ADV_2] should do the trick.

Comment: I'm very sorry I'm not best in JS but I did like this: <script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementsByClassName("myWinError")[1].parentNode.innerHTML = 'Кот Шредингера <span class="myWinError">*</span>';
document.getElementsByClassName("myBtnCont")[0].firstChild.innerHTML = 'Заправить';
}
</script> And it's didn't work

Comment: Do it without `function` because that function is never getting called. Just use commands straight: `<script>
 document.getElementsByClassName("myWinError")[1].parentNode.innerHTML = 'Кот Шредингера <span class="myWinError">*</span>';
 document.getElementsByClassName("myBtnCont")[0].firstChild.innerHTML = 'Заправить';
</script> `

Comment: Can you update the second part of HTML code above (the one you see in Chrome F12) with the lines that you added? They should be visible directly below the HTML

Comment: Really I spent huge amount looking for this problem< have tried diffrerent JS, looking for any other ways, all the same didn't work(

Comment: Basically  second part of the code is full pop up box code, where I don't have any access and where I use this [ADV_2]